# Generate VB code from an already existing Microsoft Excel document

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2013, excel-2013, vba

First of all I would like to say thank you to anyone who takes the time to answer this, your help is greatly appreciated!

What I am wondering is: if I have an .xlsx (Microsoft Excel) document that already exists (this one: http://www.sendspace.com/file/2v11gq to be precise), is it possible in Microsoft Excel to generate the `Visual Basic` code that would have generated that .xlsx document.

I know it is possible to record a macro, but I have already created the spreadsheet, so I would have to re-do it all by hand while recording a macro to get the code that I wanted.
But, the spreadsheet I am using was created by editing a template I found online, so I am not even sure exactly which properties of each cell were modified; I don't know how to recreate the spreadsheet from scratch, so even if I did record a macro it wouldn't be much help to me.

The reason I want the VB code that would generate this Excel spreadsheet, is because I am trying to programmatically generate Excel spreadsheets like this one in `C#` with the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` library, but I need to know which properties of each cell are modified in order to do so.

Is there any way to take an existing Excel spreadsheet and generate `Visual Basic` code that would generate that spreadsheet?

Thanks a ton!

Also: I am using Microsoft Office Excel 2013, and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Why would you do this instead of simply creating a copy of your existing file (as @erno de weerd suggests)?

Comment: what do you mean by "generate `Visual Basic` code that would generate that spreadsheet?"  Do you mean you want: `Range("A1").Value = "Col1Hdr"` `Range("A1").Font.Bold = True` and so on or are you after something else?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any tool  that does what you require.

My suggestion is to use the current spreadsheet as a template.

1. Either copy it, insert new values and save it
2. Or turn the spreadsheet into an actual excel template: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/save-a-workbook-or-worksheet-as-a-template-HA010218874.aspx